# Satyricon 136.7-8

Tags: classical-latin

..... post lectum occisum anserem mitto vulnusque cruris haud altum aceto diluo.

Is "vulnus" a 4th declension plural accusative noun?

If so, why is it modified by "altum", which is singular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> …post lectum occisum anserem mitto…
> *…I throw the dead goose behind the bed…*

> …vulnusque cruris haud altum aceto diluo.
> *…and wash the by-no-means-deep wound in my leg with vinegar.*

This is a neuter third declension noun, *vulnus, vulneris*. Since it's neuter, the accusative looks the same as the nominative.

This word is the source of English "vulnerable" (able to be wounded), which can be a good way to remember the stem.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's neuter 3rd declension singular. You can check with Perseus' [Morph](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=vulnus&la=la#lexicon) tool if you're ever unsure. If you then click on the definition (under Lewis and Short), you'll see the genitive ends in -is, which marks it as 3rd declension.

Meanwhile, 4th-declension nouns' genitives end in -us.

It declines as follows:

|  | sing. | plur. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nom. | vulnus | vulnera |
| Gen. | vulneris | vulnerum |
| Dat. | vulneri | vulneribus |
| Acc. | vulnus | vulnera |
| Abl. | vulnere | vulneribus |

You'll also sometimes see it spelled *voln-*.

Comment: In case you'd prefer it, [there is a table formatting option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/321340). But that's not the only option on the table, of course.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I tried doing it, and it rendered it perfectly in the preview, but when I posted it, I only saw the markup instead.

Comment: I tried to put it in a table, and it worked. I must have sacrificed to the right god... Feel free to re-edit or roll back.